# I am having trouble understanding this simple recursion problem

Tags: ruby, recursion

This code is from "The Bastards Book of Ruby" and all it does is find the largest number. It is given as an example to try understand recursion. http://ruby.bastardsbook.com/chapters/recursion/

```
def rock_judger(rocks_arr)    
  if rocks_arr.length <= 2  # the base case
    a = rocks_arr[0]
    b = rocks_arr[-1]
  else
    a = rock_judger(rocks_arr.slice!(0,rocks_arr.length/2))
    b = rock_judger(rocks_arr)
  end    
  return a > b ? a : b
end
```

To test it, I called the method with the array [1, 2, 3, 4, 30, 31, 32, 34] and investigated what is happening exactly using the pry-byebug gem.

The first time it runs, it runs the slice! method on the array, and we get [1,2,3,4]. This again runs, and it does the slice! method again, returning [1,2]. Then at this point, it assigns a = 1 and b = 2.

[image: 1]

Now here we reach the return method. 2 > 1, so it returns b. But instead of returning just the integer 2, it goes back to **line 15**!

[image: 2]

My question is, how is this possible? Should this not just return 2?

Comment: Don’t forget that a method returns its result to where it was called.

Comment: Small note: `return a > b ? a : b` doesn't need the `return` since it's the last expression in the method, and `a > b ? a : b` is the same as writing `[a, b].max`

Comment: @Chris `a > b ? a : b` is not the same as `[a,b].max` when `a.<=>(b) == 0`. Instead it should be `[b,a].max`. [Example](https://replit.com/@engineersmnky/MundaneNaiveShoutcast#main.rb)

Answer (score 1):

It's easy to get mixed up when trying to trace what is happening with a recursion. As well as adding "puts" statements, it's helpful to use indentation to isolate different instances of the recursion. See if the following helps.

```
INDENT = 8
```

```
$col = -INDENT
def indent; $col += INDENT; end
def undent; $col -= INDENT; end
def pu(s); puts "#{" "*$col}#{s}"; end 
def puhline; pu('-'*(70-$col)); end
def col; puts "$col=#{$col}"; end
```

```
def rock_judger(rocks_arr)    
  indent
  puhline
  pu "rock_judger called with argument #{rocks_arr}"
  pu "rocks_arr.length = #{rocks_arr.length}"
  if rocks_arr.length <= 2  # the base case
    pu "rocks_arr.length <= 2"
    a = rocks_arr[0]
    b = rocks_arr[-1]
    pu "a = #{a}, b = #{b}"
  else
    pu "rocks_arr.length > 2"
    pu "calling rock_judger(#{rocks_arr.dup.slice!(0,rocks_arr.length/2)})"
    a = rock_judger(rocks_arr.slice!(0,rocks_arr.length/2))
    pu "rock_judger returned #{a}"         
    pu "calling rock_judger(#{rocks_arr})"
    b = rock_judger(rocks_arr)
    pu "rock_judger returned #{b}"         
  end 
  c = a > b ? a : b
  pu "a > b ? a : b = #{c}"
  pu "returning #{c}"
  puhline
  undent
  c
end
```

---

```
rocks_arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 30, 31, 32, 34]
```

```
rock_judger(rocks_arr)
  #=> 34
```

The following is displayed.

```
rock_judger called with argument [1, 2, 3, 4, 30, 31, 32, 34]
rocks_arr.length = 8
rocks_arr.length > 2
calling rock_judger([1, 2, 3, 4])
```

```
        rock_judger called with argument [1, 2, 3, 4]
        rocks_arr.length = 4
        rocks_arr.length > 2
        calling rock_judger([1, 2])
```

```
                rock_judger called with argument [1, 2]
                rocks_arr.length = 2
                rocks_arr.length <= 2
                a = 1, b = 2
                a > b ? a : b = 2
                returning 2
```

```
        rock_judger returned 2
        calling rock_judger([3, 4])
```

```
                rock_judger called with argument [3, 4]
                rocks_arr.length = 2
                rocks_arr.length <= 2
                a = 3, b = 4
                a > b ? a : b = 4
                returning 4
```

```
        rock_judger returned 4
        a > b ? a : b = 4
        returning 4
```

```
rock_judger returned 4
calling rock_judger([30, 31, 32, 34])
```

```
        rock_judger called with argument [30, 31, 32, 34]
        rocks_arr.length = 4
        rocks_arr.length > 2
        calling rock_judger([30, 31])
```

```
                rock_judger called with argument [30, 31]
                rocks_arr.length = 2
                rocks_arr.length <= 2
                a = 30, b = 31
                a > b ? a : b = 31
                returning 31
```

```
        rock_judger returned 31
        calling rock_judger([32, 34])
```

```
                rock_judger called with argument [32, 34]
                rocks_arr.length = 2
                rocks_arr.length <= 2
                a = 32, b = 34
                a > b ? a : b = 34
                returning 34
```

```
        rock_judger returned 34
        a > b ? a : b = 34
        returning 34
```

```
rock_judger returned 34
a > b ? a : b = 34
returning 34
```